# Recieving ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error on classic ASP same connection in .net works

Tags: oracle, fedora

I have 2 different application installed on a windows 2008 one is .net the other is classic ASP. They would be connecting two different databases however to help trouble shoot the issue I have both connecting to the same database.  The .NET app will connect to the database fine but the classic asp recieves following:

```
OraOLEDB error '80004005'
```

ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

/Accrual/SecuredArea/DBConnexions.asp, line 8

the Connection string is:

```
<%      
    mg_connStr =  "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(SDU=32768)(enable=broken)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=g3u0271c.houston.hp.com)(PORT=1525))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=g3u0272c.houston.hp.com)(PORT = 1525))(LOAD_BALANCE=yes)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=CFIT1D)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=SELECT)(METHOD=BASIC)(RETRIES=180)(DELAY=5) )));uid=db;Password=xxx;"
    Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
     conn.open mg_ConnStr 
Set conn1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
'conn1.open Application("C_AccrualDB_ConnectionString")
' conn1.open mg_ConnStr %>
```

Comment: Is this an all 32-bit environment?

Comment: can you post .NET connection string too

Answer (score 0):

Check your listener.log file if the service has been started. In addition execute lsnrctl services to see if the service is actually running on the corresponding instances.

The listener is not running on the default port. Has the local_listener parameter been specified in the oracle database?